# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError exception when preselect reactive form inside a dialog

Tags: angular, forms, nebular

I'm trying to implement a dialog with a reactive form, with dynamic form data initialisation.
The dialog is in an sub-component, triggered from my main component.

When I try to preselect/fill the form components, I get this error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'status-success: false'. Current value: 'status-success: true'.
```

The problem occurs only when I preselect the nb-datepicker component with an value, if use null as value, everything is fine.

Here is my code:

main component

```
<i (click)="editdialog.bookingToEdit(booking)" class="fas fa-edit"></i>
....
<ngx-booking-edit #editdialog></ngx-booking-edit>
```

subcomponent with dialog

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-booking-edit',
  templateUrl: './booking-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class BookingEditComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output() updateBookingData = new EventEmitter<Booking>();
  @ViewChild('dialogedit') editDialog: TemplateRef<any>;

  private initialData: InitialDataResponse;
  private booking: Booking;
  public bookingForm: FormGroup;
  public newContractPartner = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private  dialogService: NbDialogService,
              private initialDataService: InitialDataService,
              private toasterService: ToasterService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadInitData();

  }

  private loadInitData() {

    // REST call init data
    this.initialDataService.getInitalData()
      .map(resp => resp)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.initialData = data.body;
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error('status', err.status);
        },
      );
  }

  //this method is called from the main component with an booking object
  bookingToEdit(bookingToEdit: Booking) {
    this.booking = bookingToEdit;
    this.initForm();

    this.dialogService.open(this.editDialog, {});
  }

  private initForm() {

    const today: Date = new Date();
    this.bookingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      description: [this.booking.description, [Validators.required, MyValidators.nospaceValidator]],
      amount: [this.booking.amount, [Validators.required, MyValidators.validateAmount]],
      date: [today, Validators.required],
      capitalSource: [this.booking.capitalSource.id, Validators.required],
      category: [this.booking.subcategory.id, Validators.required],
      contractpartner: [this.booking.contractPartner.name, [Validators.required, MyValidators.nospaceValidator]],
      privatCheckbox: [this.booking.privatBookingOfUser],
    });

  }


}
```

subdialog template

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
<ng-template #dialogedit let-data let-ref="dialogRef">
  <form [formGroup]="bookingForm">
    <nb-card>
      <nb-card-header>Buchung bearbeiten</nb-card-header>
      <nb-card-body>


        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input nbInput fullWidth
                       placeholder="Buchungsdatum"
                       formControlName="date"
                       style="line-height: 1rem;"
                       [ngClass]="{
                                                'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.date.invalid && bookingForm.controls.date.dirty,
                                                'status-success': bookingForm.controls.date.valid && bookingForm.controls.date.dirty }"
                       [nbDatepicker]="formpicker">
                <nb-datepicker #formpicker></nb-datepicker>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
              <input [ngClass]="{
                                  'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.description.invalid && bookingForm.controls.description.dirty,
                                  'status-success': bookingForm.controls.description.valid && bookingForm.controls.description.dirty }"
                     class="status" fullWidth id="description" nbInput placeholder="Beschreibung"
                     formControlName="description" type="text"/>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
              <input [ngClass]="{
                                  'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.amount.invalid && bookingForm.controls.amount.dirty,
                                  'status-success': bookingForm.controls.amount.valid && bookingForm.controls.amount.dirty }"
                     class="status" fullWidth nbInput step="0.10" type="number"
                     formControlName="amount"
                     placeholder="Betrag" type="text"/>

            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
              <input nbInput fullWidth id="typeahead-format" placeholder="Vertragspartner"
                     formControlName="contractpartner"
                     type="text" placeholder="Vertragspartner"
                     [ngClass]="{
                                  'newContractPartner': newContractPartner,
                                  'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.contractpartner.invalid && bookingForm.controls.contractpartner.dirty,
                                  'status-success': bookingForm.controls.contractpartner.valid && bookingForm.controls.contractpartner.dirty }"
                     [ngbTypeahead]="searchContractPartner" class="status"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
              <nb-select nbSelect fullWidth [size]="formSize"
                         formControlName="category" placeholder="Kategorie"
                         [ngClass]="{
                                  'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.category.invalid && bookingForm.controls.category.dirty,
                                  'status-success': bookingForm.controls.category.valid && bookingForm.controls.category.dirty }">
                <option disabled [value]=null>Kategorie</option>
                <nb-option-group *ngFor="let category of initialData?.categories" title="{{category.name}}">
                  <nb-option *ngFor="let subcategory of category.subcategories" [value]="subcategory.id">
                    {{subcategory.name}}
                  </nb-option>
                </nb-option-group>
              </nb-select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
              <nb-select fullWidth [size]="formSize"
                         formControlName="capitalSource"
                         [ngClass]="{
                                  'status-danger': bookingForm.controls.capitalSource.invalid && bookingForm.controls.capitalSource.dirty,
                                  'status-success': bookingForm.controls.capitalSource.valid && bookingForm.controls.capitalSource.dirty }">
                <nb-option disabled [value]=null>Kapitalquelle</nb-option>
                <nb-option *ngFor="let capitalSource of initialData?.capitalSources" [value]="capitalSource.id">
                  {{capitalSource.description}}
                </nb-option>
              </nb-select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group input-group-sm" style="color: #a1a1e5 !important;">

              <nb-checkbox formControlName="privatCheckbox">Privat</nb-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </nb-card-body>
      <nb-card-footer>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            <div _ngcontent-c40="" class="container-btn">
              <button [disabled]="!bookingForm.valid" nbButton>
                Buchung speichern
              </button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </nb-card-footer>
    </nb-card>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

I tried to call the dialog.open method inside a setTimeout and I tried to prefill the form data inside a resolvedPromise.then(() => {...},  but without success.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem could be?

StackBlitz: [stackblitz.com/edit/github-lv7hp3](http://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lv7hp3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `change detection` explicitly after the change. Please add this snippet of code in your component and this should resolve your issue.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewChecked()
{
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Angular Docs link => https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

GitHub issue => https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15634

Comment: Hi, this does not solve the problem, the error still occurs.

Comment: @DennisG.Have you made these change for both the main and sub components?

Comment: Now I added it also to the main component and I still get the same error.

Comment: I use "@angular/core": "^8.0.0". Maybe this is a bug inside the nebular date-piker, because I only get the error when I prefill this component? All other form components working fine.

Comment: @DennisG.Can you try using ngAfterContentInit() function? ngAfterContentInit(){ this.cdRef.detectChanges(); }

Comment: @DennisG. Oops! Sorry, buddy! Can you create a simple stackblitz for this?

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lv7hp3

Comment: Hi @DennisG.there is an open issue in github regarding the bootstrap model. So the bootstrap dialog should be in a separate component?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by first init the datepicker form control with null and after the dialog was opened, I call patchValue inside a timeout. But still no idea why I can't directly  init the control with a date object.

Comment: @DennisG.Happy to hear that you have solved your problem ;) As i said this is an open issue in GitHub.

Comment: Can you link the issue, so everyone can see if it is fixed.